# How to fix execution task failure for ':compileTestJava'?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have embarked on a Java Project using `Gradle` where I have imported the necessary `Spring Boot` libs  into the `build.gradle`. As I was building the project, it gave me this error below:

**Error**

```
Execution failed for task ':compileTestJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':testCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:1.2.5.
     Required by:
         project :
   > Could not find org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:1.2.5.
     Required by:
         project : > io.rest-assured:rest-assured:4.1.2
   > Could not find org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:1.2.5.
     Required by:
         project : > com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:6.1.0.jre8 > com.microsoft.azure:azure-keyvault:0.9.3
         project : > com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:6.1.0.jre8 > com.microsoft.azure:azure-keyvault:0.9.3 > com.microsoft.azure:azure-core:0.9.3
   > Could not find org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:1.2.5.
     Required by:
         project : > io.rest-assured:rest-assured:4.1.2 > org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.12
Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

**Build.Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'


sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8


group 'AbtMainTestControl'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

// Versioning of dependencies
wrapper.gradleVersion = '5.5.1'
def cucumberVersion = '4.7.1'
def junitVersion = '5.5.0'
def restVersion = '4.1.2'
def apacheDrillVersion = '1.17.0'



repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}



dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-core-asl', version: '1.9.13'
    compile group: 'com.opencsv', name: 'opencsv', version: '4.0'

    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '1.2.5'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.drill.tools/tools-parent
    compile group: 'org.apache.drill.tools', name: 'tools-parent', version: "${apacheDrillVersion}", ext: 'pom'

    // Cucumber Pretty Report Plugin
    compile group: 'de.monochromata.cucumber', name: 'reporting-plugin', version: '3.0.9'
    
    testCompile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '6.1.0.jre8'

    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-dbcp2', version: '2.7.0'

    
    testImplementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-java:${cucumberVersion}"
    testImplementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:${cucumberVersion}"
    testImplementation "io.rest-assured:rest-assured:${restVersion}"
    testImplementation "io.rest-assured:json-path:${restVersion}"
    testImplementation "io.rest-assured:json-schema-validator:${restVersion}"

    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:${junitVersion}"
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


configurations {
    cucumberRuntime {
        extendsFrom testImplementation
    }
}

task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "io.cucumber.core.cli.Main"
            classpath =  configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['--plugin',
                    'pretty',
                    '--glue',
                    'gradle.cucumber',
                    'src/test/resources/features',

            ]
        }
    }
}


test {
    //useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperty "cucumber.options", System.properties.getProperty("cucumber.options")
}
```

I have taken out the Spring Boot libs in this case so as to see where the problem lies in the `Build.Gradle` file

Can anybody recommend solutions/help me in trying to solve the problem? Your suggestions will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version for `httpclient` -- 1.2.5 -- looks a bit off; the latest version is 4.5.12.

Comment: oh so just update the version isit? If that's the case then I will update it

Comment: gracias brother. Appreciate your help